# the relation between input and output of linear systems

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I have a question regarding to a simple LTI system
\begin{array}{l}
\dot x = Ax + Bu\\
y = Cx
\end{array}
where $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix; $B$ is of size $n\times p$; $C$ is of size $q\times n$. $y$ is the output; $u$ is the input; $x$ is the state.

I am wondering if the output $y$ and input $u$ have a positive correlation. That is, the bigger the magnitude of $u$ is, the bigger the magnitude of $y$ is. If so, how to prove it.

Comment: Would you tell us whether $A,B,C$ are assumed to be (strictly) positive?

Comment: Also, what is $x$ a function of? Is $u$ also a function or is it a constant?

Comment: They are not positive. $A$ is not a symetric matrix, $B$ and $C$ are not square matrices

Comment: If you solve the ODE system you can see that the relation between $y$ and $u$ is given by $y(t)=Ce^{At}x_0+\int_0^t{Ce^{A(t-s)}Bu(s)}ds$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_0=0$, then $u(t) \to y(t)$ implies $\alpha u(t) \to \alpha y(t)$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. This is clear from the solution:

$$y(t) = \int_0^t C e^{A (t-\tau)} B u(\tau) d\tau$$

The system is called "linear" because of this property (plus additive property). We are generally interested in the "gain" of the system for specific inputs, i.e. $\lVert y(t) \rVert / \lVert u(t) \rVert$. The maximum gain of a system for all possible inputs is called the $H_\infty$ norm of the system.

Answer (score 0):

You question is slightly ambiguous to me.

Why $u$ should depend on $y$?

If you mean you set input as $$u=Ky$$ for example through a feedback.

Then, you can write

$$\dot x=Ax+BK(Cx)=(A+BKC)x$$

For the system to be stable, all the eigenvalues of matrix $(A+BKC)$ must have negative real parts.